# Why is the useEffect hook not called after delayed setState in Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

The component:

```
function Test() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState("init");

  const testing = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("testing");
    new Promise(r => r())
      .then(() => {
        console.log("testing 2");
        setTest(1);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    testing();
  }, [testing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("test has changed", test);
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <div>{test}</div>
  );
}
```

The test:

```
  test.only("a", async () => {
    let wrapper = mount(<Test />);

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    await new Promise(setImmediate);
    wrapper = wrapper.update().find("Test");
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
```

Log:

```
  console.log
    testing

      at testing (tests/jest/specs/functional/TemplateCustomizationContent.js:18:13)

  console.log
    test has changed init

      at tests/jest/specs/functional/TemplateCustomizationContent.js:31:13

  console.log
    <Test>
      <div>
        init
      </div>
    </Test>

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/jest/specs/functional/TemplateCustomizationContent.js:132:13)

  console.log
    testing 2

      at tests/jest/specs/functional/TemplateCustomizationContent.js:21:17

  console.log
    <Test>
      <div>
        1
      </div>
    </Test>

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/jest/specs/functional/TemplateCustomizationContent.js:135:13)
```

I can't see the log "test has changed" that should be done in useEffect after `test` has changed to `1`. Why is it not called after the setTest in the Promise callback?

Comment: First of all, what does `new Promise(r => r()).then(() => /.../}, 0);`  statement mean? Why there is `0`? Edit your code, and make them correctly and executable.

Comment: @LinDu thanks, I removed the `, 0` which is indeed useless, that's a residue of code I forgot to remove. The code is already executable btw

Comment: `await new Promise(setImmediate);` appears to be inadequate to wait for two effects occurring one after the other

Comment: @Bergi well it doesn't have anything to do with effects actually, instead it aims at waiting for the micro queue to finish, thus waiting for the promise in the effect to finish.